# Use killall in a loop in bash script

Tags: bash, cat

I'm trying to kill a `cat` process that I started beforehand using a bash script, since I need to close and re-open the cat process for each loop. However currently it doesn't kill the process, and also when trying it manually while the script is running in the background, I get the message `cat: no process killed` when trying to kill it the second time. It will be the only cat process running at any given point.

The current code:

```
#!/bin/ash
while true
do
cat /dev/rs232 > /tmp/regfile
killall cat
sleep 1
> /tmp/regfile
done
```

Comment: Your script runs sequentially. `killall` runs only after `cat` terminates by itself. You can fix this by running `cat &` as a background job. But that opens the question: **when** do you want to kill `cat`? After x seconds, or after it read n bytes, or ...?

Answer (score 0):

That's because there isn't any `cat` process to kill. `cat` is being executed and as long as `/dev/rs232` outputs data, it will be written to `/tmp/regfile`.

If you wanted a time slot you can make use of `timeout` or `child processes`:

**Timeout**

```sh
while true; do
timeout 3 cat /dev/rs232 > /tmp/regfile
# Do something
> /tmp/regfile
done
```

**Child process**

```sh
while true; do
cat /dev/rs232 > /tmp/regfile &
pid=$!
sleep 1 # Or do something
kill ${pid}
> /tmp/regfile
done
```

Comment: Please don't perpetrate `kill -9` as a standard solution. Only if the regular `kill` does not work should you employ the exceptional solution `kill -9`. See also [useless use of `kill -9`.](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html#kill)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot kill the process (`cat`) unless your shell script is running / has control (again), meaning:

- the process has already terminated: in which case you don't need to kill it, or...
- it has been executed: in the background in which case you may not want to kill it immediately (?) and you should kill it in a targeted way. I.e. use `$!` variable to record PID of the last process executed in the background and then specifically kill that process.

Looking at your loop, perhaps you really are just looking for [`timeout(1)`](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/timeout.1.html) though to terminate the process after it ran for a bit if it did not finish on its own?